# Is it bad practice to dynamically generate documentation in docstrings

Tags: python, documentation, definition, docstring

Say I have a class with functions:

```
class Foo:
    def one():
        return 1
    def two():
        return 2
    def three():
        return 3
    def four():
        return 4
```

If I wanted to add a docstring (`__doc__`) to `Foo` that shows all the functions I could write out each method individually:

```
class Foo:
    """
    one()
    two()
    three()
    four()"""
```

But it could also be generated dynamically, that is created at run time:

```
class Foo:
    def one():
        return 1
    def two():
        return 2
    def three():
        return 3
    def four():
        return 4

Foo.__doc__ = '()\n'.join(dir(Foo)) # __doc__ automatically list all methods with Foo (private and non private)
```

This could also have other uses.  For example running examples of the functions actually in use.

It is less work for documenting larger modules, but that means that the performance of `__doc__` would be decreased (since this is hardly ever used in finished products I can't see this being a problem), and is no longer a constant string.

Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: What is your intention with `__doc__`? The typical use case is looking at `help(Foo)`, which should already list the methods of the class, complete with signatures!

Comment: @AndrasDeak That is true.  However I think a lot of people would check `__doc__` first.  I do want to reference *some* kind of help there rather than leaving out `__doc__` completely (which would be the alternative).  I'm still developing a large module.  It's untidy but basically I've got a class and I'm adding some functions inside that I'm still testing (they will be removed or their location will be changed to a new class depending on how they perform).   and I keep adding new functions as needed.  I don't want to document `class` manually because they may get removed an hour later.

Comment: If you don't want to document your class "manually", how is it ever going to be documented? `Foo.__doc__ = '()\n'.join(dir(Foo))` is not adding any new information that you could not get via `help(foo)`.

Comment: @mzjn It's just something to add to `__doc__` so that it doesn't say it's undefined

Comment: If you have a regular docstring in the class body, it will populate the `__doc__` attribute of the class. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring